# MySQL/PHP merge rows by row values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, select, joomla

I need a little help with MySQL select in SQL or php.
My situation:
I have a sql table like this

```
ID | organization_ID | Investment | investment_curr | paid | paid_curr | effective_from | Effective_to
1 | 195001 | 5000 | EUR | NULL | EUR | 2010-06-23 | NULL
2 | 195001 | NULL | EUR | 5000 | EUR | 2010-06-23 | NULL
3 | 195001 | 2000 | SKK | NULL | SKK | 2007-08-01 | 2010-06-22
4 | 195001 | NULL | SKK | 2000 | SKK | 2007-08-01 | 2010-06-22
```

Now I have php select (joomla), when select values by organization_id

```
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries = $db->getQuery(true);
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries
    ->select(array('organization_id',
                                    'investment_amount',
                                    'investment_currency',
                                    'paid_amount',
                                    'paid_currency',
                                    'effective_from',
                                    'effective_to'
    ))
    ->from($db->quoteName('rpo_organization_equity_entries'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('organization_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($rpo_id))
    ->order(($db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' IS NOT NULL'), $db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' DESC ');
$db->setQuery($query_rpo_organization_equity_entries);
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries = $db->loadObjectList();
```

Then Im calling foreach

```
foreach($query_rpo_organization_equity_entries as $rpo_organization_equity_entries) {}
```

Everything works right, but not the way I need it. This `foreach` returns 4 arrays, but I need merge/combine rows by columns "effective_from" AND "effective_to" (If they have the same values. and organization_id ofcourse).
So that I combine row with IDs 1 and 2, and rows with IDs 3 and 4, And instead of 4 arrays I have only 2 combine/merge arrays like this

```
XY | 195001 | 5000 | EUR | 5000 | EUR | 2010-06-23 | NULL
XY | 195001 | 2000 | SKK | 2000 | SKK | 2007-08-01 | 2010-06-22
```

how should I do it? it is better to solve the SQL and then in php?

thx

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The result you wish to get can be achieved with MySQL by using the [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/optimizer-group-by-related-conditions.html) function.

In the [Joomla docs](https://docs.joomla.org/Selecting_data_using_JDatabase#Selecting_Records_from_a_Single_Table) they are pretty clear on this one. You van use the group() function on your object.

```
//Example
$query
->select( array('catid', 'COUNT(*)') )
->from($db->quoteName('#__content'))
->group($db->quoteName('catid'));
```

In your case you would probably want to change your code into something like:

```
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries = $db->getQuery(true);
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries
    ->select(array('organization_id',
                                    'MAX(investment_amount)',
                                    'investment_currency',
                                    'MAX(paid_amount)',
                                    'paid_currency',
                                    'MAX(effective_from)',
                                    'MAX(effective_to)'
    ))
    ->from($db->quoteName('rpo_organization_equity_entries'))
    ->where($db->quoteName('organization_id') . ' = '. $db->quote($rpo_id))
    ->group('`organization_ID`, `effective_from`, `Effective_to`') //this is the one
    ->order(($db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' IS NOT NULL'), $db->quoteName('effective_to') . ' DESC ');
$db->setQuery($query_rpo_organization_equity_entries);
$query_rpo_organization_equity_entries = $db->loadObjectList();
```

I have not tested this but something in the lines of this should work.

Comment: hi peter. this doesnt work. when I use group by, SQL returns only IDs 1 and 3 (only values from column investment, column paid is NULL :( )

Comment: My guess is that it is possible for more then 2 rows to match right?

Comment: no. every organization ID has an even number of rows, where each couple is "connected" and has the same date in effective_from and effective_to. I do not understand why the database is done like this. I have to use it.

Comment: Not sure how `$db` class works in Joomla but you could select the `MAX` values for the columns where needed, i've updated my answer.